# ASP MVC - Download a file and then navigate to a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file, view

I'm developing an asp.net - MVC application and having the following issue:
When the user types a specific url, in my case:

```
http://localhost/Download
```

I want it to go to the action method, download a file and then navigate to the corresponding view to the action method:

My Code looks like that:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string filePath = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Download"];

        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);

        if (file.Exists)
        {
            Response.Clear();

            Response.ClearHeaders();

            Response.ClearContent();

            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);

            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());

            Response.ContentType = "text/plain";


            Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);

            Response.Flush();

            Response.End();
        }


        return View();
    }
```

My view looks as simple as it gets:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }
 <h2>Downloading ...</h2>
```

When I run it, I get the file, but it does NOT navigate to the view, and instead stays in the previous url.

**EDIT - ANSWER:
Thanks to @Abbas Galiyakot 
for his reply.**

Here is the updated code that does what I wanted:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
       return View();
    }


    public ActionResult DownloadFile()
    {
        string filePath = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Download"];

        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);

        if (file.Exists)
        {
            Response.Clear();

            Response.ClearHeaders();

            Response.ClearContent();

            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);

            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());

            Response.ContentType = "text/plain";


            Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);

            Response.Flush();

            Response.End();
        }

        return new EmptyResult();

    }





@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }

<h2>Downloading...</h2>


<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("DownloadFile", "Home")';
</script>
```